# CMD - Pivot / Transpose lines of file [e.g. convert 1500 lines (x1 col) --> 500 lines (x3 col)]

Tags: cmd, foreach, pivot, transpose

how please can I 'pivot' or transpose a file (i.e. turn a single-column list, into a table of data)...

**Currently...**

```
VideoA.name
VideoA.size
VideoA.bitrate
VideoB.name
VideoB.size
VideoB.bitrate
...
```

**Desired...**

```
VideoA.name, VideoA.size, VideoA.bitrate
VideoB.name, VideoB.size, VideoB.bitrate
```

| Name | Size | Bitrate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VideoA.name | VideoA.size | VideoA.bitrate |
| VideoB.name | VideoB.size | VideoB.bitrate |

**Extra Info / Context**

I'm aware people often ask 'why are you doing this?' so (if interested), here is the wider context / problem I am trying to solve...

- I have a list of files in `Files.txt`
- I have a jscript batch file `getProps.bat` that extract file properties and prints them, 1 per line
- I have written a batch file to loop through `Files.txt`, get the properties of each and write the output to `Details.csv`
- However if I have 500 files x 3 properties, this currently gives me 1500 lines, and I want 500 lines x 3 columns

```
GetProps_AllFiles.bat
---------------------

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Files.txt) do (
    getprops %%A 0,1,320 /noheaders >> Details.csv
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll ask a different "why": Why don't you change `getProps.bat` to give the desired output instead of postprocessing it with another script?

Comment: Hi @Stephan, lol it's a fair question and TBH the same thing did occur to me while I was writing this post.. The main 2 reasons I have decided to try and solve this way (at least for now) are: 1️⃣ getProps is actually a copy of the very useful [Tooltip Info.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat) which I have made improvements to, but as it uses Jscript (which hasn't been updated in 12 years) dev. can be very painful at times. 2️⃣ I thought  ability to 'pivot' list into multiple columns might be useful / reusable in future situations.

Comment: PS - Ultimately, the way I have solved this the past 20+ times is to pull the 1-column data into Excel and use a combination of [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261), ROW() and [MOD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) to pull every 1st, 4th, 7th, etc line into the column 1, then every 2nd, 5th, 8th line into column 2, etc -- and while this works, I would be nice not have to have a separate "output processor.xlsx" file and embed this function into my script if I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "standard way" (`for /f`) to read a file line by line, extended by a counter. Add the line to a string (`line`), followed by a comma (or whatever you want to use as separator), and increase the counter. Except it's the third line. Then print the string plus the current line, reset the counter and string, and repeat.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line="
set count=0
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  if !count! equ 3 (
    echo !line!%%a
    set "line=" 
    set count=0
  ) else (
    set line=!line!%%a,
  )
))>test.csv
```

Comment: #Stephan (can't seem to @ you, but hope you see this message), just to say... It worked beautifully, thanks so much.. the ability to re-use this script will save me hours in the future!  FYI: I have tweaked your solution slightly to genericise it (parameterising the filename and number of lines). I will upload this variant for reference / for anyone else that might want the code, but more than happy to (rightfully) give you the credit and accept your answer! Thanks again 

Answer (score 0):

The below is a slight adjustment to the code kindly provided by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664755/15919675) that allows a filename and number of lines to be passed into the script...

```shell
ColumiseFile.cmd
----------------

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

REM :: USAGE -----------------------------------------------------------------
REM ColumiseFile [1]File.txt [2]NumOfLines
REM > Concatenates every n Lines into 1, exporting result to File.csv
SET "File=%1"
SET /A Lines=%2

REM :: MAIN -------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Thanks to Stephan [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664755/15919675]
REM Loops through input file, compacting every n lines into 1
set "line="
set count=0
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%File%) do (
  set /a count+=1
  if !count! equ %Lines% (
    echo !line!%%a
    set "line=" 
    set count=0
  ) else (
    set line=!line!%%a,
  )

REM :: OUTPUT -----------------------------------------------------------------
REM Create .csv in same location as source .txt file
))>%~dpn1.csv
```